# Convert networkx maximum_flow output into array

Tags: python

I am currently trying to model a network flow problem by applying a max-flow-min-cut algorithm to a directed graph. I managed to create the graph and solve for the maximum flow (and flows) by using

```
nx.maximum_flow(DG, s="S", t="T")
```

what follows is:

```
(11.0,
{'A1': {'A4': 1.0, 'A5': 0, 'T': 3.0},
'A2': {'A1': 4.0, 'A8': 2.0, 'T': 1.0},
'A3': {'A7': 3.0},
'A4': {'A3': 0, 'A8': 0, 'T': 1.0},
'A5': {'A3': 2.0, 'A8': 1.0},
'A6': {'A2': 7.0},
'A7': {'T': 3.0},
'A8': {'T': 3.0},
'S': {'A3': 1.0, 'A5': 3.0, 'A6': 7.0},
'T': {}})
```

which is a two value tuple (11, and the rest in one value). Now I want to create an array that has includes the flows for, say, A1 -> A4, A5 -> A8 and A6 -> A2.

However, I am failing to create any sort of list from this, since I am quite new to Python.

Ideally, I'd end up with something like this:

```
y = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 7.0]).reshape(3,1)

[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 7.]]
```

Comment: `data[1]['A1']['A4']` gives `1.0`, `data[1]['A5']['A8']` gives `1.0`, `data[1]['A6']['A2']` gives `7.0`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is a problem.

```
import numpy as np

data = (
    11.0,
    {
        'A1': {'A4': 1.0, 'A5': 0, 'T': 3.0},
        'A2': {'A1': 4.0, 'A8': 2.0, 'T': 1.0},
        'A3': {'A7': 3.0},
        'A4': {'A3': 0, 'A8': 0, 'T': 1.0},
        'A5': {'A3': 2.0, 'A8': 1.0},
        'A6': {'A2': 7.0},
        'A7': {'T': 3.0},
        'A8': {'T': 3.0},
        'S': {'A3': 1.0, 'A5': 3.0, 'A6': 7.0},
        'T': {}
    }
)

lst = [ data[1]['A1']['A4'], data[1]['A5']['A8'], data[1]['A6']['A2'] ]

y = np.array( lst ).reshape(3,1)

print(y)
```

Result:

```
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 7.]]
```